# Значение опрератора !! в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Что значит оператор !! в Kotlin? Не смог найти инфу.

Comment: А почему бы не почитать документацию? Это же одна из базовых вещей, для этого не надо глубоко разбираться.

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka документация для слабаков)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

оператор `!!` указывает выдавать NPE, если значение, к которому применяется оператор равно null. Фактически так достигается стандартное поведение Java при null-значении.

`a!!.length` - либо вернет результат, либо кинет NPE, если a = null

[Документация русский](http://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/null-safety.html)
[Официальная документация](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator)

PS: Аксиома Кана и Орбена: Если ничто другое не помогает, прочтите, наконец, инструкцию (из законов Мерфи).